# How to validate the List parameter in c# to fix CA1062

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, fxcop

I have following code. I getting the FxCop violation. I do not know how to validate the List parameter.

```
 public Collection<ProjectData> IsHookedConfiguredList(Collection<ProjectData> groupProjectList)
    {
        if (groupProjectList.Count != 0)
        {
           // my code
        }            

        return hookConfiguredList;
    }
```

I added the line `if (groupProjectList.Count != 0)` But I did not rid violation.

How could I fix this?

Comment: What is your function going to do if the input is null? Should it throw, propagate the null, return an empty collection?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There is no chances to be a null input.

Comment: @Aruunkumar of course there is - `var tempList=null;(10 lines after that); var newList=IsHookedConfiguredList(tempList);`.Check the input parameter and decide how to handle the inevitable null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code Analysis wants you to check whether passed argument is null before you use it. Try this:

```
public Collection<ProjectData> IsHookedConfiguredList(Collection<ProjectData> groupProjectList)
{
    if (groupProjectList == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(groupProjectList));
    }

    //  the code
}
```